# Custom Post Type - Seperate Posts on Archive Page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom post type for 'products'. This works great and I am feeding my advanced custom fields for product name, product description and a product image (using featured image). I created my archive page and named it .../store/. I made two test products and they are both are feeding into the archive page fine. The problem I'm having is that they are connected and not separated.

I know this has to do with my variables that are calling the same custom field for each product. Here is my code for .../store/:

```
<div class="store-wrap">

<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10'
  );
  $products_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $products_loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $products_loop->have_posts() ) : $products_loop->the_post();
      // Set variables
      $title = get_the_title();
      $description = get_field('product_description');
      $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' );
      $product_image1 = $featured_image[0];
      // Output
      ?>
            <div class="product">
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">

        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        <img src=<?php echo $product_image1;  ?> alt=”<?php echo $title; ?>”>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php echo $description; ?>
</a>
      <?php
      endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;
?>
            </div>
          </div>
```

If you look at the page http://dev.thefooddepot.org/store/, you can see that they are connected. How do I separate these? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are missing a closing </div> for your opening <div class="product"> in your while loop.

Comment: Yes, it was below the while loop. Thanks.